# Why is that when I run ''forge init'' on Foundry, it says "Program not found"

Tags: ethereum, solidity

There are just seven lines in the foundry book to install foundry (ethereum) but i am having some issues.
First, in the foundry documentation there is this: "Download and run rustup-init from rustup.rs. It will start the installation in a console" but anytime I do, Rust just closes immediately I press  the enter button.
Secondly: I already installed foundry because if i run foundry --version it shows the version downloaded but forge init isnt working. A picture is attached.

[a picture of what forge init is saying after downloading foundry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ju2W.png)

I already checked google, but i couldnt get help, please help. [Click here to see the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObKF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Comment: Maybe you trying to init in wrong folder, first go in .cargo then bin, create new foulder in there and open it with VScode or editor that you use, after try again forge init.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't get the problem, turns out forge init tries to initialize a git repository, so you need to run it in git bash.